# Bootstrap contact form

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

**So I am using this tutorial http://www.html5templatesdreamweaver.com/bootstrap-form.html

I get emails from my website when I test the form, but the email doesn't contain the form info. It says "inquiry"

Here is my

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>BOTW v.4</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
```

Here is my form

```
               <fieldset>                      <form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Enter name">
                  </div>
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputMessage1">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" input type="message" rows="3" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
                  </div>

                    <div class="actions">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull    -right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
                    </div>  
                    </form>     
               </fieldset>
```

**And finally my Javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="email/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

Edit -  and my php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="bryanontheweb@yahoo.com";
 $subject="Enquiry!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email        
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com
 }
?>
```

Comment: This `<textarea class="form-control" input type="message" rows="3" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>` should not contain `input type="message"` and where is your PHP? None of your form elements are named. If your PHP is depending on it, then that's most likely the reason it's failing. Show us your PHP.

Comment: Need to see your php. Also your scripts are Javascript not Java.  Two separate languages.

Comment: You need to name your form fields with the "name" attribute before you can use them in PHP with the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You need to put the "name" attribute for the input and textarea

```
<fieldset>                      <form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Enter name">
                  </div>
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
                    <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputMessage1">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" input rows="3" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
                  </div>

                    <div class="actions">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull    -right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
                    </div>  
                    </form>     
               </fieldset>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this into my index.html. No change.

Comment: can you try to print and see if $message is showing the proper message that you want?